# Installing Deis in AWS without ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, deis, big-ip

I'd like to install a Deis cluster in AWS but without using ELB, since we have already paid for an alternative (BigIP), and our network guys are comfortable with it.

Is it trivial to configure Deis not to use ELB, and rely on BigIP instead?

[Edit] I'd like to have a ballpark figure of the amount of additional work necessary to have Deis work with BigIP as compared to a standard Deis cluster in which 2 ELB instances are automatically created.

Comment: Is there something specific you have a question about? Are you more asking about Deis configuration, BIG-IP configuration, architectural/deployment choices?

Comment: @JasonRahm I've edited my question to make it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: if your network team is comfortable with BIG-IP I can't imagine you'd have any problems with it versus ELB. BIG-IP does stock load balancing very well, but has quite a few more services that can be layered on top if desired. That said, if the ELB configuration is already automated with a stock Deis deployment (i'm not familiar with it) you will need to customize the BIG-IP deployment on your end. We do have some ansible automation tools on github: https://github.com/F5Networks/aws-deployments/